# What is the function that will truncate string in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm still new to PHP and I couldn't find this in the manual because I'm not sure of the name of the function.  I have an array with These values:

```
$files[] = 

[0] => 01_Nhemamusasa.mp3 
[1] => 02_Kari_Mudande.mp3 
[2] => 03_Chikende.mp3 
[3] => 04_Karinge_Zuva.mp3 
[4] => 05_Mbirimo.mp3 
[5] => 06_Muchenjedza_Mutonga.mp3 
[6] => 07_Skokianna.mp3 
[7] => 08_Mbavarira.mp3
```

What I need to do is truncate the contents to get rid of the part before the _ and get rid of the filetype.  I'd like to also convert the underscores found in the middle of the Arrays [1] and [5] (in this example) to become spaces.  In other words, I need to convert these file names to be an array of the actual names of the songs.

Thank for any help!

Edit: My host is using PHP 5.2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = array(
    '01_Nhemamusasa.mp3',
    '02_Kari_Mudande.mp3',
    '03_Chikende.mp3',
    '04_Karinge_Zuva.mp3',
    '05_Mbirimo.mp3',
    '06_Muchenjedza_Mutonga.mp3',
    '07_Skokianna.mp3',
    '08_Mbavarira.mp3'
);

function convert($item) {
    $item = explode('_', $item);
    unset($item[0]);
    $item = implode('_', $item);
    $item = explode('.', $item);
    $item = str_replace('_', ' ', $item[0]);
    return $item;
}

$output = array_map('convert', $input);

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Nhemamusasa
    [1] => Kari Mudande
    [2] => Chikende
    [3] => Karinge Zuva
    [4] => Mbirimo
    [5] => Muchenjedza Mutonga
    [6] => Skokianna
    [7] => Mbavarira
)
```

Comment: it should be noted that this requires PHP5.3+

Comment: Looks great, but my host is running 5.2.12 :(

Comment: @Gordon I assume the inline function was the part that made this require 5.3+?

@Joel I reworked the code to not use an inline function, so you should be able to use it now.

Answer (score 3):

Using combination of array_map(), preg_replace() and str_replace():

```
$array = array(...);

$array = array_map(function($item) {
    return str_replace('_', ' ', preg_replace('#^\d+_(.*?)\.[a-z0-9]{2,6}$#i', '$1', $item));
}, $array);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: it should be noted that this requires PHP5.3+

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the array_walk function: https://www.php.net/array_walk
If you are using PHP 5.3, you can pass array_walk an anonymous function.

EDIT: array_map will also do the trick as well. Same advice about anonymous functions apply here as well.

Comment: You can use lambdas with PHP < 5.3 when using `create_function`

Comment: @Gordon: This is certainly true and since you brought it up, it should also be noted that the caveat regarding create_function is that you will likely end up escaping the code. Many developers find this ugly and would rather write a one-off class/method and pass it through via an array [ array('class', 'method') ].

Comment: yeah, it aint pretty with create_function and it's slow as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate the array and use [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the first three chars, again for the last four or each string.

After that you can use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to change the underscore with a space.

Answer (score 0):

both php string replacement functions (str/preg_replace) accept arrays as the "subject" argument:

```
$files = preg_replace('~^\d+ (.+?)\..+$~', '$1', 
    str_replace('_', ' ', $files));
```